# "Page not found" when accessing a custom module

Tags: forms, 8

I have created the custom registration module for drupal8. I define the path on routing.yml file but when access that module on browser side I got "Page not Found" message.  Here the sample code.

#### custom_form.routing.yml

```
    custom_form.register:
path: '/custom_form/my_form'
defaults:
 _form: '\Drupal\custom_form\Form\Formsettings'
 _title: 'Registration page'
 requirements:
  _permission: 'view user registration form'
```

#### custom_form.module

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
/**
*@file
*custom_form.module
*/
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
/**
* Implementation of hook_permission()
*/

function custom_form_permission() {
  return array(
    'submit custom_form' => array(
      'title' => t('Submit custom_form'),
      'description' => t('Submit the custom_form Form'),
    ),
  );
}

/**
* Implementation of hook_menu()
*/
function custom_form_menu() {
$items=array();
    $items['custom_form/my_form'] = array(
     'title'=> 'My Example Form',
     'route_name' => 'custom_form.register',
     );
    return $items;
  }
```

Comment: Your YAML is invalid

Comment: And `hook_menu()` is not used from Drupal 8.

Answer (score 3):

As stated, YAML has very specific spacing rules.

```
custom_form.register:
  path: '/custom_form/my_form'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\custom_form\Form\Formsettings'
    _title: 'Registration page'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'view user registration form'
```

Try that spacing, and Formsettings will need to be a form controller in custom_form/src/Form if it isn't already - you didn't link to it.

Both hook_permission() and hook_menu() are no longer used, so you'll want to remove them from the code base. (though I don't think they will stop it from loading properly.)

Comment: I did some changes which you have said in routing.yml file but still I have the same issues

Comment: Are you clearing your cache? If you're using Drupal Console the command is 'drupal cache:rebuild all', otherwise you can go manage -> configuration -> performance -> clear cache.